# Reading objects from a file ClassCastException error

Tags: java, file, serialization, arraylist, classcastexception

I am trying to write an ArrayList  of Question objects called questions to a file, then reading the file.

My problem is that when I am reading the file, it gives me an error that says: **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Question at Quiz.load**

My question is, why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it? I've been reading a lot of tutorials and they just cast the object to the class name which is what I did. I included my save & load functions.

Inside Quiz class:

Write Objects To File

```
    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    //filename given by user
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(questions);
```

Read Objects From File

```
    ArrayList<Question> readQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    System.out.print("QUIZ LOADING...");

    readQuestions.add((Question)ois.readObject()); //problem occurs
```

Comment: Perfectly simple. You serialized a String and tried to deserialize it as a Question. So clearly this is not the code that was actually executed to produce the file. This is further proven by the fact that this code does nothing except serialize an empty ArrayList. It is *further* proven by the fact that your code serializes an ArrayList but tries to deserialize it as a Question, which doesn't begin to make sense. I can only suggest you post the real code.

Comment: Hi EJP, thank you, I will just post the code in a bit. I will modify it because it also has GUI stuff and it's way too long.

Comment: @EJP Do you mean this recent one? The one I posted before just did not have the Scanner & imports, so I just added that. The full code has GUI in it and it's very long since I used NetBeans' drag and drop which autogenerates code. This current code can be compiled/ran on terminal and it still shows that ClassCastException

Comment: I am asking why you posted code that had nothing to do with how the exception you are asking about was actually produced. It is a complete and utter waste of everybody's time. Don't do it.

Comment: @EJP That's what I thought so too. I misinterpreted your comment of "real code" as the "whole code" since a snippet of a code doesn't represent the real code. I guess what you meant was to put the relevant code of the problem. I will the remove unnecessary code.

Comment: You didn't post a 'snippet'. You posted code that didn't produce the error. It was not the real code. The real code has `writeObject(questions.toString())`. The code you originally posted did not: it had `writeObject(questions)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing a  list and deserializing it with Question.

Just change

> readQuestions.add((Question) ois.readObject()); //problem occurs

with this

> `readQuestions = (ArrayList<Question>) ois.readObject();`

Further explanation :
When i tried the example i got this error :
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Question
So most likely if you are getting ClassCastException with String, you are also missing Serializable interface on Question. Something like this :

```
class Question implements Serializable {
    String text;

    public Question(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Adding working code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ObjectIS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ObjectIS().save();
        new ObjectIS().load("abcd");
    }

    public void save() {
        try {
            ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
            questions.add(new Question("what is your name"));
            //filename given by user
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("abcd");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(questions);

            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void load(String filename) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Question> readQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            System.out.print("QUIZ LOADING...");

//            readQuestions.add((Question) ois.readObject()); //problem occurs
            readQuestions = (ArrayList<Question>) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("ois = " + readQuestions);
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class Question  implements Serializable {
    String text;

    public Question(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Question{");
        sb.append("text='").append(text).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but it doesn't explain the actual exception reported.

Comment: I've tried that too and I get this new error: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        readQuestions = (ArrayList<Question>)ois.readObject();
  required: ArrayList<Question>
  found:    Object
1 warning

Comment: @EJP  Edited with explanation, does that make sense?

Comment: No. If Question wasn't Serializable it would produce a different exception. Not a ClassCastException from String.

Comment: Acutally you are right, when i removed Serializable i got this error : java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Question. I am not sure how to get ClassCast with String. :)

Comment: I am. Serialize a String. As I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have an empty box. You put an apple into the box.

Then you close it, and open it later on. Now, do you think it would work out to expect to find a hamburger in that box?

But that is what you are doing - storing a String and expecting to find a Question object. And that class cast exceptional is how the jvm tells you about reality not fitting your assumptions.

Solution: either store question objects - or expect strings to come back when reading the file.

Comment: Right. So what you are saying is that whenever I store the objects in my ArrayList, that is stored as a String? and when I read the objects from the file, I cannot read them as Question objects since they were stored as String?

Comment: @HaiHey No, he just said that you stored something different from what you tried to read. The only person that stored anything as a String was you, in your real code, that you still haven't provided.

Comment: @HaiHey No. What I am saying is: when **you** put apples in the box then *you* put **apples** in the box. Your code does what you tell it to do. It stores String objects. Not Question objects.

Comment: @EJP Code is posted

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly as I said. You are serialising a `String`:

```
 oos.writeObject(questions.toString());
```

And then attempting to deserialize it as a `Question`, which it never was:

```
(Question)in.readObject();
```

Solution:

- remove the `.toString()` part.
- deserialize as a `List<Question>`, which is what it really will be.

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: What happened when you did?